# Maintain 2d array shape following mask indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, a.shape is [2,1000,1000] and b.shape is [1000,1000].

b has 0s and 1s in it. I want to use those to index the first dimension of a and output a 1000,1000 size array. The methods I've tried so far don't maintain the shape of the original array.

Comment: How exactly do you expect that to work? Let's say `b` has 200 ones. The best you can hope for is a (2, 200) output, unless you use a masked array. Please provide a lot more information or an example or something.

Comment: To be more precise, how do you define your output tensor? I can imagine how one could define a tensor of size `[2, #{ones in b}]`, like `output[i, j] = a[i, j s.t. b[i, j] = 1]`. What do you mean by indexing by the mask in this case? Should remaining values be zeros? If so, you can just multiply them: `output = a * b[None, :, :]`.

Comment: something like this maybe? a[1,:,:][b==1]+a[0,:,:][b==0]

Comment: Try something like `k, l = np.ogrid[:1000, :1000]` `a[b, k, l]`

Comment: @BenUsman thanks! Your solution to just use multiplication worked. Wish i'd thought of that one earlier.

Answer (score 1):

A twist on a previously suggested answer (with input matrix size of 10 instead of 1000...):

```
a = np.random.rand(2, 10, 10)
b = np.random.rand(10, 10) > 0.5  # created a random mask

c = np.zeros(b.shape)
c[b == 0] = a[0, :, :][b == 0]
c[b == 1] = a[1, :, :][b == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you can do

```
np.where(b, *a[::-1])
```

A more general approach applicable also when a has not two but n layers would be

```
k, l = b.shape
k, l = np.ogrid[:k, :l]
a[b, k, l]
```